# How to do a SQLIte query to search words in a dictionary

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I created a table with 4 columns: _id(Auto increment), Vocab(text), Meaning(text) and favorites(Numeric). Now i created a search query like the following:

```
  public class StudentRepo {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;


    public StudentRepo(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    public Cursor  getStudentListByKeyword(String search) {
        //Open connection to read only
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor=db.query("dictionary",new String []{"_id","Vocab","Favorite"},"Vocab LIKE ?", new String[]{"%"+search+"%"},null,null,null);



        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;


    }
}
```

Please find the searchbar code:

```
     @Override
///@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);


  // if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit ");
                cursor = studentRepo.getStudentListByKeyword(s);
                if (cursor == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No records found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cursor.getCount() + " records found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                customAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

                return false;
            }
```

DBHelper code:

```
      public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    //version number to upgrade database version
    //each time if you Add, Edit table, you need to change the
    //version number.
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Dictionary.db";

    public DBHelper(Context context ) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed, all data will be gone!!!

        //Toast.makeText(DBHelper.this,"Just Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

Whenever i run the app and click on search bar to start searching word, my app stops working. Please find the Logcat output

```
       05-09 13:46:58.931 2178-2178/com.example.doctor.searchwidget 
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                      
    Process: com.example.doctor.searchwidget, PID: 2178
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor
com.example.doctor.searchwidget.StudentRepo.getStudentListByKeyword(java.lang.String)' 
on a null object reference 
at com.example.doctor.searchwidget.MainActivity$2.onQueryTextChange(MainActivity.java:145)
at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1150)
at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.access$2000(SearchView.java:103)
at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$12.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1680)
at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7663)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4050)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3905)
at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:85)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3880)
at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onActionViewExpanded(SearchView.java:1265)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter.expandItemActionView(Toolbar.java:2026)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.expandItemActionView(MenuBuilder.java:1323)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.expandActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:687)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:963)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

MainActivity.java :145 points to "getStudentListByKeyword(String search)"

I tried changing query but all efforts failed. I somewhere foudn on stackoverflow that this happens due to not connecting to sqlite database, Kindly help me out.

MainActivity Code:

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionButton;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionMenu;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.SubActionButton;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    public Cursor cursor;
    public StudentRepo studentRepo;
    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName().toString();

    private static final String TAG_BOOKMARKS="bookmarks";
    private static final String TAG_ABOUT_US="about";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchResult.class);
                intent.putExtra(SearchResult.EXTRA_NO, (int) id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        };


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstStudent);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        databaseAccess.open();
        List<String> quotes = databaseAccess.getQuotes();
        databaseAccess.close();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotes);
        this.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Done Testing


        ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_action);

        FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                .setContentView(imageView)
                .build();
        ImageView Bookmarks=new ImageView(this);
        Bookmarks.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_action);
        ImageView Aboutus=new ImageView(this);
        Aboutus.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_action);
        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
        SubActionButton buttonbookmark = itemBuilder.setContentView(Bookmarks).build();
        SubActionButton buttonaboutus = itemBuilder.setContentView(Aboutus).build();
        buttonbookmark.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonaboutus.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonbookmark.setTag(TAG_BOOKMARKS);
        buttonaboutus.setTag(TAG_ABOUT_US);


        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
                .addSubActionView(buttonbookmark)
                .addSubActionView(buttonaboutus)
                .attachTo(actionButton)
                .build();



    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);


            SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
            search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

            search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit ");
                    cursor = studentRepo.getStudentListByKeyword(s);
                    if (cursor == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No records found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cursor.getCount() + " records found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    customAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextChange ");
                    cursor = studentRepo.getStudentListByKeyword(s);
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        customAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });



        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getTag().equals(TAG_BOOKMARKS)){
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Bookmarks.class));
        }
        if (v.getTag().equals(TAG_ABOUT_US)){

        }

    }
}
```

after initializing studentRepo, i am getting new error:

```
05-14 01:45:44.506 2142-2142/com.example.doctor.searchwidget E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.doctor.searchwidget, PID: 2142
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.example.doctor.searchwidget.CustomAdapter.swapCursor(android.database.Cursor)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.doctor.searchwidget.MainActivity$2.onQueryTextChange(MainActivity.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1150)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.access$2000(SearchView.java:103)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$12.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1680)
                                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7663)
                                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4050)
                                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3905)
                                                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:85)
                                                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3880)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onActionViewExpanded(SearchView.java:1265)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter.expandItemActionView(Toolbar.java:2026)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.expandItemActionView(MenuBuilder.java:1323)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.expandActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:687)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:963)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Looks like studentRepo is null, where are you initialising it?

Comment: @SirKuryaki   Sorry, I didn't understand that. I initialized it in search bar code. I am building a dictionary app, so i only showed the searchbar code. I am taking data from external database. When i was using only dummy data, code was working as expected but now it's creating problem.

Comment: paste the code where you are calling  studentRepo = new StudentRepo

Comment: @SirKuryaki: Please find the main activity code below

Comment: @SirKuryaki: I edited the question with MainActivity code which calls StudentRepo.

Comment: You are not initializing the studentRepo...

Comment: @SirKuryaki Thanks for helping me out but now i have new error.

Comment: @RicardoBarroca...I initialized and now i am having a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

studentRepo isn't initialised, add this line inside MainActivity's onCreate method (below setContentView)

```
studentRepo = new StudentRepo(this);
```